# How is ThreadPool implemented in .NET 4.0?

Tags: multithreading, .net-4.0, threadpool

I recently tried to work out how the solution to a ThreadPool class works in .NET 4.0. I tried to read through a reflected code but it seems a bit too extensive for me.

Could someone explain in simple terms how this class works i.e.

1. How it stores each methods that are coming in
2. Is it thread safe, supposedly multiple threads try to enqueue their methods in the thread pool?
3. When it reaches the limit of available threads, how does it return to execute the remaining batch waiting in the queue when one of the threads becomes free? Is there some callback mechanism for it?

Comment: FYI, the ThreadPool class is part of .NET, not part of C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, in the absence of the actual implementation (or in the absence of Eric Lippert :) ) what I'm saying is only common sense:

1. The thread pool holds an internal (circular?) queue where the tasks are kept (hence `QueueUserWorkItem`).
2. Putting tasks in the queue is thread-safe (this is for sure, as I've used myself in this scenario several times).
3. I think that each thread loops indefinitely and keeps taking tasks from the queue (in a thread-safe manner of course) automatically when it's done with the current task. If the queue is empty it will just block.

Comment: I have no particular arcane knowledge of how thread pools are implemented. Your explanation seems plausible.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Wait, how did you know this post mentions you? AHA, so you do have some kind of hidden powers. Either that or M$ is monitoring my every move.

Answer (score 1):

1. In a queue of delegates
2. TBH, I don't know for sure but, if it's not, it's dangerous, nearly useless and probably the worst code ever emitted by M$, (even including Windows ME).  Just assume it's thread safe.
3. The work threads are while loops, waiting on the work request queue for a  delegate, invoking one when it becomes available, then looping back round again when the the delegate returns to wait on the queue again for another delegate.  There is no need for any callback.

Comment: Note in .NET 4 it is a delegate queue per thread in the pool with work stealing to balance load. This has been documented on MSDN blogs (start with the Parallel Programming team: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/).

Comment: @Richard - I suspected so, but did not want to complicate matters - the overall design and effect is the same, the queue-per-thread and work-stealing is a performance enhancement.

Answer (score -1):

1. I don't know exectly but to my mind it stores it in a collection of
   Task
2. MSDN says yes
3. GetMaxThreads() returns the amount of onetime-executed threads if
   you reach this border all others are queued. As I understand you
   need mechanism  for knowing when thread is executed. There is 
   RegisterWaitForSingleObject(WaitHandle, WaitOrTimerCallback, Object, Int32, Boolean)

Comment: Point 1 is definitely not true. The thread pool was implemented long before the Task class was created for .NET.